# parse multiple pages without change in url address

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, web-scraping, lxml

I wish to parse table contents from [here](https://www.mutualfundindia.com/MF/return/TopFunds). However, the table continues into multiple pages. My problem is that I cannot parse pages from `page 2` onwards since there is no change in the `url` address. How can i locate the `url` address where other pages are stored? I am using `lxml` and `requests`.

Comment: You need to use `selenium` to start a browser so you can have `javascript` load the page dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you open Chrome DevTools and click "2" on the pagination control, you will see a request made by the script to fetch date for the page "2":

```
POST https://www.mutualfundindia.com/MF/return/TopFundDetails?page=2
```

with Form Data:

```
__RequestVerificationToken:AYv1N1VEGXTeLKMbnHolT_bste-CiFcH1GAjQgh1O7c_Ygm0-wIP3j47yN6e5tzYx3EumwCRBYcxI6825nH28W_qO60ZMlnAm4f1utRjqL4wgokl87pgsV4anV4vKtSjk6XV0g2
Rank:-1
Type:-1
Nature:-1
SubNature:-1
cmdAum:1
Period:1Year
ShortingOrder:DESC
hdHeaderId:1Year
```

You can find the value for __RequestVerificationToken on the page, in the element:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken"...
```

The response of the request is pure HTML.

I guess, if you make such requests, you parse all the date.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to write a small code to explain the above. I am trying to understand the above solution but I don't know where is pagination control ...the link to page 2 is in a tag <a href...> but nothing happens when I click it!